# SharePoint 2007 on Server R2 Core

Tags: 2007, installation, infrastructure

Has anyone tried to configure SharePoint 2007 on Windows Server R2 CORE?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't one of the operating systems supported for SharePoint 2007 installation by Microsoft (at time of writing).

It would be an interesting experiment but if your installation would be unsupported I'm not sure it's a good idea.

**Update:** Tried this out but found running setup.exe did absolutely nothing, presumably because of missing components of the .NET Framework as Woody mentions. To do anything further would be hacking around.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the .Net framework and the inclusion of graphics related bits that did not work on Core.

I know people have tried and failed to do this install and see this fail.